# Reverse in test gives me back a 404

Tags: python, django, django-tests

my test below returns a response 404. If I replace the **'party:detail'** by **'/party/party/1'** , now it will pass. Per the documentation, I do pass the parameters correctly, so what is causing the issue?

```
class UrlTests(TestCase):
    def test_login_client(self):
        User.objects.create_user('buddy', 'me@me.com', 'password')
        self.client.login(username='buddy', password='password')
        response = self.client.get(reverse('party:detail', kwargs={'pk': '1'}))
        self.assertEqual(301, response.status_code)
```

**demo\urls**

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^party/', include('party.urls', namespace='party')), ]
```

**party\urls**

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^party/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', login_required(PartyView.as_view()), name='detail'), ]
```

**party\views**

```
class PartyView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Party
    template_name = 'party/party.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Party.objects.filter(pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
```

Comment: whats exact traceback?

Comment: Where do you create the Party object with id 1?